# Set Datarow column of SQLDateTime to Null

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm loading up some ADO.net objects:

```
    Dim conPERP As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(OISConnectString)
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("", conPERP)
    daCERTs.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PERP_Certs_DMS", conPERP)
    Dim cmdBldr As New SqlCommandBuilder(daCERTs) 
    daCERTs.Fill(dsCERTs)
    daCERTs.FillSchema(dsCERTs, System.Data.SchemaType.Mapped) ' later troubleshooting attempt
    dtCERTs = dsCERTs.Tables(0)
```

Using SQL Server 2008. One of the columns in dtCERTs is of SQL type datetime. The column is nullable. A report has a value already but I need to set it back to NULL.

```
        sWhere = $"registrationNo={c("regNo")} AND Instance_ID={sInst}"
        row = dtCERTs.Select(sWhere)(0)
        row("Why_Archived") = DBNull.Value ' varchar - works
        row("Record_Archive_Date") = SqlDateTime.Null ' causes error
```

Last line causes error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime'
to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <Null> 
in Record_Archive_Date Column.  Expected type is DateTime.
```

Null.Value doesn't work.

SqldateTime.Null.Value causes error: "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

How do I set the datetime column to NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
row("Record_Archive_Date") = DBNull.Value
```

As you have for the `varchar`